# Picking this and calculation in Isabelle/JEdit output

Tags: isabelle, isar, user-experience

This is a follow-up to

[How to write a low-level proof in Isar?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2052/how-to-write-a-low-level-proof-in-isar)

Having

```
lemma por_qandr_imp_porq: assumes "p ∨ (q ∧ r)" shows "p ∨ q"
proof -
  note assms
  moreover
  have "p ⟹ p ∨ q"
    by (rule p_imp_porq)
  moreover
  have "q ∧ r ⟹ p ∨ q"
    by (rule qandr_imp_porq)
  ultimately
  show ?thesis
    by (rule disjE[of p "q∧r" "p∨q"])
qed
```

if I point the cursor after `ultimately`, Isabelle/JEdit's Output window shows

```
proof (chain)
picking this:
    p ∨ q ∧ r
    p ⟹ p ∨ q
    q ∧ r ⟹ p ∨ q 
calculation:
    p ∨ q ∧ r
    p ⟹ p ∨ q
    q ∧ r ⟹ p ∨ q
```

where calculation is in grey background. The contents of the `picking this` and the `calculation` parts are identical, but what is the difference between the two in their meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each step accumulating facts (i.e., each of `moreover` and the final  `ultimately`), the proof state will show the *fact* `calculation`—which you can quote inside the proof, by the way.

AFAIK, this is redundant in the final step since both lists are the same. But the `picking this` message is useful since it indicates that those facts will be used (“chained”) for the next inference (which does not occur at `moreover` steps). If you actually want to use all of them amidst that block, you may invoke `moreover from calculation`.